# Set error message for block of asserts in phpunit

Tags: phpunit

Is there a way to set an error message for *X* number of asserts inside a block? I'm trying to provide more meaningful error messages and currently have a section of my testing code that looks like:

```
    $helperString = 'testInsert() @ test conflicting reasonid';
    $this->assertEquals(..., ..., $helperString);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ..., $helperString);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ..., $helperString);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ..., $helperString);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ..., $helperString);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ..., $helperString);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ..., $helperString);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ..., $helperString);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ..., $helperString);
```

which works, but it's pretty ugly. I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
    $this->setMessage($helperString);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ...);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ...);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ...);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ...);
    $this->assertEquals(..., ...);
    ....
```

Does functionality like this exist? I'm not aware of how to proivde better output in phpunit other than something like `Failed asserting that 1 matches 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be such functionality built in - but you could easily add your own assertion test, such as:

```
$this->assertNotConflictingReasonid($x, $y);
```

and then in the function, have your custom message, should the test fail. Depending on what, and how your tests want to do, they may also customise the message based on the inputs, or comparison.